# SQL query limit and offset error on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, limit, offset

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3'' at line 1
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_testimoni order by id DESC limit 3 offset '3'
>
> Filename: D:\wamp\www\obatrohanifinalcopy\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Hello, I’m having problem with my query syntax. I think the problem is in `limit` and `offset` query. Because I have tried without `limit` and `offset` and my script can work properly. But the pagination function doesn’t work according to my wish.

This is my controller:

```
$url=$this->uri->segment(3,0);
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url().'/testimonial/all/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tbl_testimoni')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['page']=$this->pagination->create_links();
        
        $sql = " SELECT * FROM tbl_testimoni order by id DESC limit 3 offset ? ";
        $binds = array($url);
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, $binds);
        $artikel = $query->result_array();
        $data['action'] = 'testimonial/all';
        $data['artikel'] = $artikel;
        $data['content'] = 'content/testimoni';
        $this->load->view('template/default', $data);
```

and in my view the pagination was called using this code:

```
<?php if(!empty($page)) echo $page; ?>
```

and my code doesn’t work properly.

**Note:** I was using this controller and view in my previous website but there I was using PostgreSQL and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try typecasting the `$binds` variable as in `$this->db->query($sql, intval($binds));`

Also, by the documentation `$this->uri->segment()` may return boolean, so you might want to handle that as well.

Comment: still same like before sir. the result on next pagination still same like first page. not appears the next data

Answer (score 0):

The offset should be a number not string '3'

when you pass the $binds in `$this->db->query($sql, $binds);` the DB Driver think its a value and replace your ? with '3' where it should be `OFFSET 3`

Comment: results are not performing well. just called multiple databases and when I click on the pagination. the result is the same as the start page appears

Comment: If its give always same result then the problem could be in the url segment, can you check what value you are getting from your uri segment also you can `echo $this->db->last_query()` to see the last query what exactly its executing.